# Adding a PWA to existing app. Are there benefits?

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps

I have a client with two mobile apps. The first **APP1** is built natively using Java and Objective-C. The second **APP2** has been build using Unity.
Now the client wants to add a common functionality to both **APP1** and **APP2**. The functionality is some new promo screens with user interaction to win credits.

I was considering to propose WebViews for this, however I came across to Progressive Web Apps.

I would like to ask whether is it possible to add a PWA in existing apps by properly initializing WebViews. I guess that the answer is 'yes'. But is there any benefit (apart from the caching) from using PWA instead of common HTML pages since the mobile app is already there?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't list what kind of capabilities are required of your PWA in a WebView. From my understanding WebView doesn't support the Push Notification API, see this research paper on [What is in a Web View? An Analysis of Progressive Web App Features When the Means of Web Access is not a Web Browser](https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub46739)

Comment: Great paper @MorrisonChang.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PWA is nothing more than a regular HTML webpage, which has added bonus functionality. Those bonus functionality is the incredible ease of install (if not on iOS, at least), and the offline capabilities.

The offline capabilities mostly means that the app will work (for the most part), even when no internet is available.
The easy install functionality means that if you open the site on Chrome for Android, you can "install" the app directly, without going through the app store. This doesn't work properly on iOS, however.

However, at the end a PWA is still just a webpage. This means that it is not just an app for iOS, or Android. It is an actual webpage, with an URL you can surf to. Installing a PWA just takes a local copy, and displays it in such a way that it *looks* like a native app.

So, in your case, there is no real bonus of making a PWA. If I read correctly, you just need to add a simple HTML page to both apps, right? You can make this a website, and then use WebView to navigate to it, sure. But there is no need to make it a PWA; it will just run in the native app itself.